# grid-row-end to show time slots

Tags: css

I am trying to show time slots booked using CSS and am having trouble figuring out how to use grid-row-end properly

```
.row {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto repeat(14, 50px) auto;
grid-gap: 1px;
background-color: #CCC;
padding: 1px;
}
[data-span="1"] { grid-row-end: span 1; }
[data-span="2"] { grid-row-end: span 2; }
[data-span="3"] { grid-row-end: span 3; }
[data-span="4"] { grid-row-end: span 4; }
[data-span="5"] { grid-row-end: span 5; }
[data-span="6"] { grid-row-end: span 6; }
[data-span="7"] { grid-row-end: span 7; }
```

https://codepen.io/joe420/pen/dgyYjq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are making each row a grid container, instead you need to make all the calendar a grid. Considering this solution you will need to also remove some empty cells each time you have a bigger one.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto repeat(14, 50px) auto;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  padding: 1px;
}

.slot {
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.booked {
  background: #FF0000
}

.label {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

[data-span="1"] {
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}

[data-span="2"] {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

[data-span="3"] {
  grid-row-end: span 3;
}

[data-span="4"] {
  grid-row-end: span 4;
}

[data-span="5"] {
  grid-row-end: span 5;
}

[data-span="6"] {
  grid-row-end: span 6;
}

[data-span="7"] {
  grid-row-end: span 7;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="time">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="label">Slot</div>
    <div class="label">Slot</div>
    <div class="label">Slot</div>
    <div class="label">Slot</div>
    <div class="label">Slot</div>
    <div class="label">Slot</div>
    <div class="label">Slot</div>
    <div class="label">Slot</div>
    <div class="label">Slot</div>
    <div class="label">Slot</div>
    <div class="label">Slot</div>
    <div class="label">Slot</div>
    <div class="label">Slot</div>
    <div class="label">Slot</div>
    <div class="time">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="time">1AM</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="booked" data-span="3">Booked</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="time">1AM</div>
    <div class="time">2AM</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="time">2AM</div>
    <div class="time">3AM</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="time">3AM</div>
    <div class="time">4AM</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="time">4AM</div>
    <div class="time">5AM</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="time">5AM</div>
    <div class="time">6AM</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="time">6AM</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That helps, thanks! It's probably less work to build the grid and position the bookings on top of the correct slots.  You have pointed me in the right direction and I appreciate the help